# java решение уравнения

Tags: java, while

Помогите решить задачу на java, не понимаю как решить эту задачу без ввода X, Y.

Задача: 
Дано натуральное число n.
Определить количество решений неравенства х<sup>2</sup> + у<sup>2</sup> < n в натуральных числах.

Пример работы программы:

```
Введите n: 30
Ответ: 9
```

Получилось решить эту задачу только с вводом X и У, не как не могу понять какие значения должны быть в X и У, если нужно вводить только N.

Код программы:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x,y,n,s = 0;
    x = in.nextInt();
    y = in.nextInt();
    n = in.nextInt();
    if (x > 0 && y >0 ){
        while (y*y + x*x < n){
           y = y+ 1;
           x = x + 1;
           s = x+y;
        }
    System.out.println("Ответ: "+s);
    }
```

Comment: `for x=1 to fix(sqrt(n)):for y=1 to fix(sqrt(n-x*x)):print x,y`

Comment: @Akina а это точно java? больше на python походит.

Comment: Это не ява и не питон. Это просто демонстрация того, что задача - элементарнейшая.

Answer (score 0):

Ниже решение задачи про `x + y < n`, квадраты в вопросе не были очевидными.

---

Немножко размышлений и задача становится элементарной.

Сколько существует сумм `x+y=n`?
Это `1+(n-1)`, `2+(n-2)`, ..., `(n-1)+1`, всего `n-1` вариаций.

Теперь, сколько `x+y < n`? Это сумма `k - 1, для k < n, или k <= n-1`
Итого, получаем `сумму чисел от 1 до n-2`. При `n=1,2` результат будет `0`.

```
public static int foo(int N) {
  if (N < 3) return 0;
  return (N-1)*(N-2)/2;
}
```

В случае трактовки "натуральных чисел", как включающих 0, размышления не изменятся, а результат даже чуть упростится.